# Is it possible to merge multiple disconnected lines in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I am working on a graph visualization project and there is a performance problem, because the nodes are connected through simple lines, where each edge is represented by a `THREE.Line`. This causes too many render calls.

One possible solution would be to use a `THREE.Line` for each connected component, but I was wondering if there is a more general solution.

In three.js it is possible to merge multiple geometries into a single geometry, but is there also a way to merge multiple disconnected lines into a single geometry?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [three.js r72 no longer supports THREE.LinePieces, how to merge multiple disconnected lines with THREE.LineSegments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915473/three-js-r72-no-longer-supports-three-linepieces-how-to-merge-multiple-disconne)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can render multiple line segments with a single draw call by using `THREE.LineSegments`:

```
var line = new THREE.LineSegments( geometry, material );
```

three.js r.107

Comment: answer is outdated. current answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915473/three-js-r72-no-longer-supports-three-linepieces-how-to-merge-multiple-disconne

Comment: @scones Thanks. Fixed.