# merge multiple lines in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

**What I want**merge multiple lines into one line to improve performance(lines maybe line,polyline(closed),arc,circle,ellipse). Encountered a problem [#1370](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1370),the same dpatro described.

**What I found**I found the solution:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915473/three-js-r72-no-longer-supports-three-linepieces-how-to-merge-multiple-disconne),my code was below:

```
case "Line":
            var startPoint = me.stripStringToPoint(entity.StartPoint);
            var endPoint = me.stripStringToPoint(entity.EndPoint);
            var p1 = new THREE.Vector3(startPoint[0],startPoint[1],startPoint[2]);
            var p2 = new THREE.Vector3(endPoint[0],endPoint[1],endPoint[2]);
            geometry.vertices.push(p1);
            geometry.vertices.push(p2);

            var line = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, material);
            return line;
            break;

        case "Polyline":
            var vertices = entity.Vertices;
            var color = me.stripStringToColor(entity.Color);
            for (var j = 0, len1 = vertices.length; j < len1; j = j + 2) {
                var p = new THREE.Vector3(entity.Vertices[j], entity.Vertices[j + 1],0);
                geometry.vertices.push(p);
            }
            if ( entity.Closed === true && geometry.vertices.length >0) {
                geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(entity.Vertices[0], entity.Vertices[1],0));
            }

            var line = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, material);//
            return line;


var mergeGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
mergeGeometry.merge(line.geometry, line.matrix);
scene.add(new THREE.LineSegments(mergeGeometry,material ));
```

I use three.js r.73 while he use r.72,does this matters?needs your help~

Comment: What do you mean "the connection between lines still exist"? Can you be more clear about the problem? Try to explain what your expected behavior is, what the actual behavior is, and how they differ.

Comment: I f i understand correctly, OP is putting spatially separated line segments in a single line object. It is a single line, then there is a line connecting the distinct parts. Instead, use the geometry object's built in merge function. Create the line parts in their own for loops. See the merge function on this page: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Geometry  If the OP's method must be used, I would set the material of the offending segment to visible = false; I don't know what type of performance increase would result though?? Perhaps OP is attempting to simplify rotations or the like.

Comment: @JCD sorry for my unclear describle first ,I edited it and hope it helps.

Comment: @Radio I'm so  sorry that I don't understand "Instead, use the geometry object's built in merge function. Create the line parts in their own for loops."  I use the  geometry built in merge function now and how to create the line parts  in their own for loops?

Comment: I misunderstood your question, sorry. I see now, that the merge itself is what your question is about. I think you need to use a different pattern. Although you're using lineSegments, you're also using merge, and you're seeing the problem of connections between lines. For a proper use of THREE.LineSegment, see code lines 49-64 at: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/canvas_materials.html